# aws-amplify Auth.currentSession() not giving refreshed token after an hour

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

*Which category is your question related to?*

AWS amplify auto handling refresh token

*What AWS Services are you utilizing?*

aws-amplify

*Provide additional details e.g. code snippets*

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) 
{ return Auth.currentSession() .then(session => { // User is logged in. 

  Set auth header on all requests 
  let accessToken = session.idToken.jwtToken; 

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = accessToken; 
  return Promise.resolve(config); })
   .catch(() => { 
  // No logged-in user: don't set auth header 
  return Promise.resolve(config); 
}); 
});
```

This is the interceptor request I'm using for now to get latest valid token irrespective of the total time, since user is logged-in as #446 and aws-amplify documentation tells that it is automatically refreshing token internally and `Auth.currentSession()` gives you the latest valid jwtToken every time.

But what I experience is: I login: `Auth.currentSession()` keeps giving me the jwtToken that was received when logged_in. After an hour, the token was expired and `Auth.currentSession()` was still giving this previous expired token which caused my server to send me 401. How do I handle it? How do I keep getting latest valid refreshed jwtToken? Am I using it wrong, or is it a bug?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Any answers from AWS to this issue? I'm facing the same problem in my application

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late for you, but if anyone else stumbles on this thread, you are probably using 'token' as your Authorization grant flow. Use 'code' instead. Dont forget to change that in cognito console as well. Select Authorization Code grant instead of implicit grant